# Retrieving MAX Value Using ActiveRecord

Tags: ee2, channel-entries

I am trying to get the maximum value of the entry_id within the exp_channel_titles field of an ExpressionEngine2 database using the following code:

```
ee()->db->select_max('entry_id');
$query = ee()->db->get('exp_channel_titles');
echo "<pre>";
   var_dump($query);
echo "</pre>";
```

Above code only gives me this:

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)[674]
  public 'conn_id' => resource(45, mysql link)
  public 'result_id' => resource(386, mysql result)
  public 'result_array' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'current_row' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => int 1
  public 'row_data' => null
```

How could I get the actual MAX value from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution. Since select_max will only result in one row you will not need to loop through all rows like a normal query. Just use $query->row();

```
        ee()->db->select_max('entry_id');
        $query = ee()->db->get('exp_channel_titles');

        echo $query->row();
```